# Image of interior of a unit disc under a complex transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

If $w=T(z)=\sqrt{\frac{1-iz}{z-i}}$, then what is the image of $\{z : |z|<1\}$ under $T$ ?

I rewrote $T$ as $T(z)= e^{\frac{1}{2}log(\frac{1-iz}{z-i})}$, and found image of interior of unit disk under $\frac{1-iz}{z-i}$ but doesn't able to move forward. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The image of the unit disk $\mathbb D = \{z\in\mathbb C||z|<1\}$ by $\frac{1-iz}{z-i}$ is the upper half plane $\mathbb H = \{z\in\mathbb C|\Im z>0\}$. It is a Möbius map, and you can check this by directly computing the imaginary part of the forward map and the modulus of the inverse. Taking the the principal branch of the square root, the image of $\mathbb H$ is the upper right quadrant (halve the argument).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I also got image of unit disc under $\frac{1-zi}{z-i}$ as the upper half plane. It's the rest I'm stuck with. I didn't quite get your briefing

Comment: Look at the effect of the transformation on complex numbers in polar form.